# How to deduce L7 information from a traffic

Tags: networking, network-programming, sdn, mininet, openflow

Is it possible to know which application has generated a certain traffic (maybe via Layer 6 or Layer 7)? I used Wireshark to see if I can get such information especially from the first packet of the flow, i.e. SYN packet when TCP transmission is used. However, I found out that this does not exist as the first packet SYN is a part of the handshaking process. Only last packet of the stream is able to show information about L7 payload from which I can deduce what application has generated this flow.

Comment: What is "L6" and "L7"? And no there is no possible way to deduce application transferring data until there actually is data being transferred to use as basic of the deduction. TCP/IP have no notion of "applications", or the protocols on the application layer.

Comment: Thank you so much. L stands for Layer